# How to get Chatbase data to show on Dashboard

Tags: chatbot, chatbase

Struggling to find some forum to get help on this.

We've started using chatbase and are struggling to see our data in the dashboard. The API returns 200's with message_ids. Anyone able to point me in the right direction in terms of how to debug this further?

Have followed the docs here: https://chatbase.com/documentation/generic and their 'codelab'. Issues logged on github and tweeted.

Some of our data does show up - specifically the Intents and some of the 'Session flows', but the rest is blank. No messages, no 'active users' ever.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?

Comment: @JayHewitt yes. It was an issue with Chatbases code and the format of the data we were sending. Guess I'll post that as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this was resolved by Chatbase updating their code and by us updating the timestamp to match their docs, i.e.:

`"time_stamp: int, milliseconds since the UNIX epoch, used to sequence messages"`

The full issue was discussed over on Github: https://github.com/google/chatbase-dotnet/issues/1

Comment: Thanks @JPThorne, I'd not done milliseconds, but also wasn't aware of the 6 hour update